# Remove string and space in second column of text file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to remove a particular string "num= " from the second column of a **TAB-DELIMITED** text file.

```
this is a sentence  num= 123.45
this is a phrase    num= 768.90
```

I know how to remove "num=" using sed, but I can't seem to be able to remove the space after '='.  What I want is this:

```
this is a sentence  123.45
this is a phrase    768.90
```

Additionally, if the second column number is greater than 500, I would like to flag the row in a third column, like this:

```
this is a sentence  123.45  true
this is a phrase    768.90  false
```

**What I tried:**

I used awk to get the second column into it's own file and then this:

```
sed -e s/num=//g -i            # Removes just "num="
sed -e s/num= //g -i           # I get an error 
sed -e s/num=\s//g -i          # No effect
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: I used awk to get the second into it's own file and then this sed -e s/num=//g -i.  That doesn't remove the space after "num=" and I lose 1st column.  I tried sed -e s/num=\s//g -i, but that doesn't work.  I tried sed -e s/num= //g -i  as well and I get an error.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }                  # set delimiters to tab
{ 
    sub(/num= /,"",$2)                 # remove num= 
    print $0,($2+0>500?"true":"false") # output edited record and true/false
}' file
this is a sentence  123.45  false
this is a phrase    768.90  true
```